# New User interface site edit 2011 SP1 is not working in Internet explorer when we clicked on the SDL Tridion button

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

When i am clicking on the SDL Tridion button its is redirecting to tcm but with the message Page not found! Editing is not possible.

Comment: And it works with a different browser?

Comment: Are you getting anywhere with this? Did you try anything else?

Comment: Thanks for your question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you specified the correct URL in the "Enable inline editing for Page" Template Building Block within your Page Template.

If you are unsure if it is correct, try opening it in your browser -- that should show the toolbar and a white page saying "Page not found! Editing is not possible."

The URL would normally be `http://yourserver/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/`.